# Find distribution of Bus arrival time

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning, distributions, multiple-regression

I am currently working on a problem in my research which can be modeled into the following question:

Let's say I have a **rich dataset** with values for the variable $A$ which is equal to `Time to Arrival of the next Bus` and variable $W$ which is equal to `Wait time of the next Bus in the bus stop`.

**How can I find the distribution of $A$ and $W$ to use it in my analytical model.**

Following figure is a illustration of the data set just for one day. Where the red intervals are time intervals that Bus was waiting in the target bus stop.

[image: sample bus stop history]

I know that $A$ and $W$ have relation with other dynamic values of the system that are $Q,L,R$. These are independent variables that has been sampled from the system at the same time that $A$ and $W$ is sampled. Therefore, $A$ and $W$ should be functions of $Q,L$ and $R$:

$A=f(Q,L,R)$

$W=g(Q,L,R)$

I don't know the distribution of $Q,L$ and $R$ and not sure even if I need to know that. I am just interested to know the distribution of $A$ and $W$ variables. I am not sure also if there is a true relation ship between $A,W$ and each one of $Q,L$ and $R$ and what is $g$ and $f$. I am just guessing that intuitively there should be some relation.

Notes:

- This question is related to [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134574/estimate-probability-of-being-in-a-time-interval).
- This is not a self-study question. It is an issue in my academic research.